# Stressing a quality of an object in comparisons

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

If I am not wrong, stressing a quality of an object right before the object is permissible in English with the word "quite":

> He is **quite naughty a** boy.
>
> She is **quite beautiful a** girl.
>
> It is **quite difficult a** task.

If I am right here, would it also be okay in English to do the same while comparing an object to another one on the point of that quality that is being stressed?

> The release of the album was quite **more important an event** than
>   the Grammy award giving that came half a year later and was merely a
>   logical response to that event.

In the example above, the first object is "event", second object is "the Grammy award giving", the quality being stressed is importance (expressed by the adjective "important")

Comment: COCA returns nothing for "quite <adjective> a" - the usual way to stress the quality would be "He is quite a naughty boy", "She is quite a beautiful girl", etc.

Comment: @Lambie because that indicates that the construction used by the OP is either not correct or very narrowly used (my money is on it being a mistake, but I'm not sure, maybe in some dialect?)

Comment: He is quite naughty a boy is not always wrong but better is: He's quite a naughty boy. In any case, there is no comparison there at all.

Comment: My money's with Maciej.

Comment: The first three examples are not grammatical. Your fourth sentence is not grammatical either. It should be: X was **a much more important event than** Y.

Comment: Also note that *quite more* is a very unusual collocation in English. I would say that it's never used. After a cursory search in google ngram viewer, nearly all examples seem to be from foreign writers, possibly just bad translations.

Comment: For the first three, the article is in the wrong position.  Do you know where it's supposed to go?  Perhaps check [Quite + nouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quite#:~:text=When%20we%20use%20quite%20with%20a%20gradable%20adjective,until%20they%20were%20out%20of%20sight.%20%28%2B%20adverb%29)

Comment: Quite [adjective] a [noun] is often used in poetry. That was my point.

Answer (score 0):

He is quite a naughty boy. [no comparison, just an intensifier, adverbial]
She is quite a beautiful girl.
It is quite a difficult task.
Note the order of the words.

The release of the album was **a much more important event than** the Grammy award event....

Grammy award giving would be wrong above.

That's the comparative.

Comment: either "was a much more important event than" or "was much more important an event than"

Comment: @Doarn - Do you mean that both options are okay in English?

Comment: Yes, but mine is more formal.

Comment: @brilliant I think there was originally a typo because both "a" and "an" were used, I was pointing out either one or the other work but not both; It's been corrected in the main answer now.

Comment: Why would "Grammy award giving" be wrong?

Comment: Because we don't say: X is a more important event than Grammy award giving. You are either comparing two events or not. You can't compare AN event to "award giving". That's why.  You have to compare comparable things. Album releases are more important than Grammy events. Releasing an album is more important than receiving a Grammy.

Comment: Why is "award giving" not an event? (Perhaps, my understanding of the English word "event" is  wrong. In my first language an award giving would definitely be considered an event)

Comment: I am talking about grammar and parallelism. Events are comparable. Actions with gerund nouns are comparable. Award giving is an important activity and it occurs at events. Award giving is not  in and of itself an event. And "an award giving" is not used. An award-giving ceremony, yes.

Comment: @Lambie: "Award giving is not in and of itself an event" - Why not? I am sorry for being annoying here, but one of Webster's definitions for 'event' is "something that happens, occurrence" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/event). How is award giving (or giving an award) not something that happens?

Comment: @brilliant - *award giving* is not wrong.  It's just a bit odd to use in this context. Just delete "giving". It's redundant. All awards are "given" - an award is literally (a payment, a certificate, a trophy, compensation, etc) given in recognition of something.

Comment: @BillyKerr - But could just "the reward" be an event then?

Comment: This event is much more important than that event. I just think the word event should be repeated for a **comparative**: This ball is redder than that ball.

Comment: No. Not a "reward".  An "award" is the thing you are given, be it money, a trophy, a certificate, in recognition of some achievement.